# Cassandra issues in production

Tags: cassandra

I am looking at using a system with Cassandra as a backend, and I wanted to collect together common problems that people experience in production Cassandra environments with usual workarounds/solutions.

Could anyone tell me of their experiences, as I want to see what potential showstoppers/issues I need to think about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.riptano.com/docs/0.6/troubleshooting/index